# How to set resulted Data in query while updating in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-update

My question related to MySQL ,

how to set data which is result from where condition

for example ,
in tbl_user there is status column
now i want to update status column with starting letter current existing word in status column

existing data

tbl_user

```
useid | status
sam      Active
jam      Inactive
```

what i want after updating

```
useid | status
sam      A
jam      I
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below - `left(status,1`) will give you the first character of your status field

```
update tbl_user set status=left(status,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want to keep only the first letter of the `status` field, which you can achieve with the `left()` function:

```
update tbl_user set status=left(status,1)
```